# Specific issue regarding MathJax, then (auto?) save to word or pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, asp-classic, ms-word, mathjax

Look, this might be a dupe question, and apologies if it is... but honestly, everything I've found on the subject seems to be from 2007, or calls out special caveats for IE6 and the like.

The setup:
Web page using math markup and MathJax to render the math in the web page (working fine).

The user(s) need to be able to export this to some sort of doc - word, PDF, etc - for distribution to proof-readers who are not permitted/desired to be "in the system" where the pages are served.

The issue:
Everything I've tried thus far to get the rendered final product out to some sort of doc - OTHER than doing a user-initiated browser-print - shows the unrendered markup and not the final product.

This is obviously due to the way the MathJax library renders the page when it's fully available, in the browser, as it's just a JS script inclusion. No surprises there.

I can get *close* by doing an ajax call to a page that renders, and sending that whole blob of html to a third page to write out to disc and re-serve it with mime and content disposition headers for msword, saving it to disc, etc., but the rendering is not correct - presumably due to packaging it up in a POST call. And that's a lot of steps to end up with a not-quite-right solution, anyway.

I'm guessing the answer is going to be "you can't do that", at least not without using one of the HUGE installs of TeX Live or MikTex, etc., and doing it in the back end with shell calls... but I don't have the ability to install on these hosts anyway.

Am I stuck with users doing a print-to-PDF solution? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks, happy to flesh out where needed, but I can't be the first trying to do this.

Comment: Not sure I follow. It sounds like you are after a way to turn HTML to PDF on the server with MathJax processing along the way. Is that about right? (docx is a whole different mess and less likely to work afaik)

Comment: Correct, yes. I need to make it rendered and portable, without the final user(s) needing to be online and/or have the MathJax libs installed. 

And to be fair, we're evaluating a number of options, including read-only access to the system and/or publishing the html to a Wiki or something and let folks proof it there. Portable, post-rendered docs would be best, however.

And again, I'm fairly certain the answer will be "you can't do that" (without using TexLive or similar processing engines) and that's a fine answer. Just making sure I'm not missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**For PDF** there are a couple of options and it mostly depends on how much work you want to put in.

The quick and dirty solution might be [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), but you'll have to [specify a wait time](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1543) for JavaScript rendering to finish -- not ideal.

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) requires slightly more work but allows you to listen in on the page, e.g., [this discussion](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1029#issuecomment-72348069) links to a simple example. (There are lots of PhantomJS-based tools out there actually.)

Another way would be to first pre-process using [MathJax-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/MathJax-node) and then pass the result to wkhtmltopdf (then you don't have to wait for MathJax).

**For doc/docx** I don't think there is any way right now. The natural way would be to use MathJax-node to generate MathML, since Word can import MathML. But Word does not seem to support MathML when imported from HTML. The same holds for generating SVG with MathJax-node (but with SVG you would loose the ability to edit the equations so that might be prohibitive anyway).

Pandoc might eventually help. It can apparently convert mathematics to the MS Office format, see [demo #30](http://pandoc.org/demos.html)). But from a quick test this doesn't seem to work for HTML input right now.

Comment: I'm less concerned with the complexity of any implementation as I am in getting consistent, repeatable and quality-formatted results. The things I've looked at so far have been horrible, and thus far we're leaning toward just publishing the HTML with JIT MathJax rendering via typical script includes to something like a wiki or other display engine and moving away from doc-based portability. It just seems better, simpler and as noted, more consistent and repeatable. Thanks for the info; I'll look at MathJax-node, too.

Comment: I suppose I still don't understand what you are actually after.

Comment: I guess I'm not being clear. I want to pre-render mathjax formatting into a self-contained document to hand around, not relying on proofreading users being connected to the 'net and not using the mathjax js library for view-time rendering. * shrug *

Comment: Right. In your comment above you mention some requirements about rendering quality while the original question seemed to be about an equivalent to "print to PDF". Generally speaking high quality HTML to PDF is hard (especially without any knowledge of the HTML and CSS involved), html to docx is probably hard (but primarily very different). Adding math into the mix increases complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering commercial solutions, have a look at pdfChip from callas software (warning: I'm heavily affiliated with this solution).

It does HTML to PDF and will actually convert MathML using MathJax into a proper PDF file (that can even be a PDF/X or PDF/A file if you so desire). I'll be happy to provide more details off-line.

Comment: I'm not the guy who makes buying decisions. I write code, analyze, design and solve. Money guys are the ones to make the ultimate decision. I'll take a look at PDFChip and if there's a demo, I'll give it a whirl. We're not afraid of spending the right money on a commercial package. Thanks.