# Convert Mathjax ouptut in a readable format for jqmath

Tags: latex, wkhtmltopdf, mathjax, jqmath

On a project, I use ck editor with mathjax plugin in order to insert some formulas.

In a another part of this project, I would like to use jqmath. Cause it's faster and more integrated in wkhtmltopdf (I use those formulas in some docs produced by wkhtmltopdf, and some issues exist with mathjax, especialy over bar).

My problem: syntax is different between mathjax and jqmath. Of course, jqmath doesn't care about my formulas syntaxed under mathjax...

So my question is: does it exist a way to convert maths strings from mathjax to jqmath syntax?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Both MathJax and jqmath use MathML internally and both understand it as an input format (jqmath added MathML input support a while back, see the copy-me.html in the distribution). So you can generate MathML from MathJax and feed that into jqmath.

Comment: For PDF generation with MathJax, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/30433735. You might also want to check out MathJax's CommonHTML output which is very fast and somewhat like jqmath's output.